# Build.SERIAL is deprecated as of API 25: Android 7

Tags: xamarin.android, deprecated, serial-number

What should i use insteas of Build.Serial in our application in Api 25 and below because it was deprecated. Any suggestion thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `getSerial` method and as far as I remember you need `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in Manifest.

```
var serial = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O ? Build.GetSerial() : Build.Serial;
```

The old API still works in the lower versions of Android.

Comment: But Build.Serial is deprecated right? currently we are using above as it is, but upcoming we are change so Build.Serial instead of any other property?

Comment: So the thing is that it was deprecated in Android O and all the devices before it should use the old code...